# Why this is not decrypt?

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, char

I'm writing a program to encrypt the text in C++ with a specific key and a half reduce algorithm. It works perfectly but when I want to decrypt the same text and I want return the cipher text to plain it gives me wrong chars. This is an encrypt function:

```
int encryption()
{
    cout << "please enter the plain text" << endl;
    char LUT[] = "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn";
    char message[100];
    char ch;
    int i;

    cin.getline(message, 100);
    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        ch = message[i];
        if (isupper(ch))
            message[i] = toupper(LUT[ch - 'A']);
        else
            message[i] = LUT[ch - 'a'];
    }

    cout << "the cipher text is equal to"  << message << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's normal that when I press

> a

I'll get

> o

also for

> b is p

But when I want write the reverse function for the same thing it doesn't work. I mean when I want add the pressed char to 'a' index it gives me the wrong char. Actually it should return

> a

when I press

> o

and this is my function:

```
int decryption()
{
    cout << "please enter the cipher text" << endl;
    char LUT[] = "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn";
    char message[100];
    char ch;
    int i;

    cin.getline(message , 100);
    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        ch = message[i];
        if (isupper(ch))
            message[i] = toupper(LUT[ch + 'A']);
        else
            message[i] = LUT[ch + 'a'];
    }

    cout << "the plain text is equal to" << message << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

thanks to any suggestion or tell me where I have an semantic error

Comment: You have to provide a reverse lookup table for the decrypting function. Your decrpyt function does encrypt your ciphertext a second time. As a side note, you should replace message with std::string, and std::cin.get with std::getline(std::cin, message)

Comment: I think your question would benefit from moving the problem (`decryption` not working as expected) to the top and the explanation (how the `encryption` is working) to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you said half reduce algorithm. Basically your encoding string should have been

`char LUT  [] = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm";`

In which case, applying the same encoding algorithm would have brought you back the original string. It has to be the first 13 characters at the end and the last 13 characters at the beginning (rotating the alphabet 13 times)

But if you want to keep your encoding string(12 rotions to the left), then the decoding string should be

`mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl`

(12 rotations to the right). Except that you must use the exact same algorithm.

(`ch-'a'`  and `ch-'A'`)

Answer (score 4):

Your code assumes [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.

With ASCII the value of `'o'` is `111` and the value of `'a'` is `97`. So when you do `ch + 'a'` what you're really doing is `111 + 97` which is equal to `208`. Not a valid index of your `LUT` array.

You should *continue* to use `ch - 'a'`, and modify your `LUT` array to be the opposite translation instead, so `'o'` maps to `'a'` instead of the opposite.